# how to send data from node.js to angular?

Tags: angular

server ( node js )

```
app.get('/api/GetFlux',function(req,resp){
  let data = "hello"
  resp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

Client (Angular)

```
GetFlux():Observable<any[]>{
  return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrlNode+'/GetFlux');
}


this.service.GetFlux().subscribe(data =>
      {
        this.fluxList = data;
      });
```

fluxList undefined why ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are sending a string back. If you really want to send a string back you need to amend your service with:

```
return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrlNode+'/GetFlux', { responseType: 'text'});
```

JSON is the default responseType. What your api is sending and your service need to match. If you really meant to send json which is what you would normally do, you need to amend your api to:

```
resp.json(data);
```

Really depends on the nature of the **REAL** data you are sending.

Comment: if i want to send array string can i  do that with json format ? and how i do it at angular level

Comment: @Marouane if you are sending an array from the api to angular then you would just amend the api to resp.json(data);
No other changes required on the Angular side.

Comment: @Marouane but I wouldn't recommend stringifying the array before send, there's no need and against best practice